# How to convert type Object from engine.eval to type int

Tags: java, javascript-engine, scriptengine

My program takes a String input and calculates it using `engine.eval()` from ScriptEngine imports. How do I convert the evaluated value to type int?

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "206 + 4";
    Object eval;

    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine eng = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    try {
        eval = eng.eval(s);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println("Error evaluating input string.");
    }

//Convert Object eval to int sum
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a `BigDecimal` and then get the `intValue()` from it.

```
int val = new BigDecimal(eval.toString()).intValue();
```

Note that `intValue()` will trim the `Decimal` in the result. If you want to throw an exception, in case that is happening, use `intValueExact()` which throws an `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: I have another question out of curiosity. Suppose I wanted to convert is to type long. How would this be achieved?

Comment: That's where `BigDecimal` is the winner. Use `longValue()` instead of `intValue`.

Answer (score 1):

ScriptEngine returns Double for any arithmetic expression, so cast it to Double and use its intValue method

```
    int res = ((Double) eng.eval(s)).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = Integer.valueOf((String) eval);
```