# How can I save Strings from my JavaScript evaluation, in a Java String? Example below

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I have JavaScript I need to execute, String.fromCharCode() to be specific. I would like to save this result in a Java string accessible in the rest of my program.

I have I've started working with the Nashorn Script Engine. I can evaluate the JavaScript, but I'm unsure of how to save the result in my Java object.

`Object result = engine.eval("print(String.fromCharCode(+((!![]+!![]+!+[]+!![]+!+[]+!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!!+[]))));");`

The result of this is "P"

How can I access this answer from Java?

Comment: The fact that you have `print` in there is going to make the result null/void

Comment: Will I be able to cast "result" as a String?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415888/how-to-convert-type-object-from-engine-eval-to-type-int this shows you have to convert the return value from eval to a string